# Changing order in array struct column and adding new elements - SPARK SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this schema1 :

[image: schema1]

Im trying to sort the elements on the struct and also add some new elements as NULL in any position as in the schema2:

[image: schema2]
I tried this :

```
df.withColumn("sample",
    expr("transform(sample, x -> struct(x.elem1, x.elem2, 'NULL' as elem2, x.elem3,x.elem4, x.elem5, x.elem6 , x.elem7))"))
```

I've got this error :

> Only foldable string expressions are allowed to appear at odd position, got: NamePlaceholder,NamePlaceholder,NamePlaceholder,NamePlaceholder,NamePlaceholder,NamePlaceholder,NamePlaceholder; line 1 pos 45;

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
sparkSession.sql("select array(named_struct('elem4', 4, 'elem1', 1, 'elem2', 2)) sample").
      selectExpr("transform(sample, x -> named_struct('elem1', x.elem1, 'elem2', x.elem2, 'elem3', null, 'elem4', x.elem4)) sample_rewired").
      show()
```

works producing:

```
+-----------------+
|   sample_rewired|
+-----------------+
|[{1, 2, null, 4}]|
+-----------------+
```

using struct will introduce generated column names for the nulls so:

```scala
sparkSession.sql("select array(named_struct('elem4', 4, 'elem1', 1, 'elem2', 2)) sample").
      selectExpr("transform(sample, x -> struct(x.elem1, x.elem2, null, x.elem4)) sample_rewired").
      selectExpr("explode(sample_rewired) no_array").selectExpr("no_array.*").
      show()
```

yields:

```
+-----+-----+----+-----+
|elem1|elem2|col3|elem4|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
|    1|    2|null|    4|
+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

as such you'll want to specify names via named_struct.

As to the error you've got, no idea, it looks odd.  Using withColumn and expr also doesn't fail.  What Spark version are you on?